# How do I set the selected value of a dropdown in Orbeon Forms using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dropdown, orbeon, setvalue

I need to set the selected value of a dropdown control in an Orbeon Form using Javascript, passing in the VALUE (not position) of the required option.

For simple controls (text fields), from the documentation, I can do:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue((ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "CONTROLID-control"]')).attr('id'), "NEWVALUE")
```

And also from the documentation, I can get the selected value of a dropdown using this:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.getValue(ORBEON.jQuery(ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "DROPDOWNID-control"]')[0]).find('.xforms-select1')[0])
```

Actually, that code retrieves the position in the dropdown of the selected value, e.g. "5". But anyway, I couldn't find a way to set the selected value of the dropdown using a VALUE and not a POSITION.

I built my Form using Form Builder and my dropdown is pre-populated using an Action and an HTTP Service. This is my populate action:

https://ibb.co/JsH635s

So I'd like to pass a NAME (value, NOT Position in dropdown) to the selector control to set it as a selected value.

Something like this:

ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue((ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "local-branch-control"]')[0]), "MYVALUE")

I tried different combinations but none of them worked. Is this even possible in Orbeon?

Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with ORBEON, but since you can get to the select element, are you able to jQuery further to the options within the select? jQuery `o$Opts=$("#mySelect:options)` would give you an array with all the options, and you could then loop through them `for(var i=0;i<o$Opts.length;i++){if(o$Opts[i].text()=="valueYouWantSetAsSelected"){o$Opts[i].selected=true;break;}}`

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it works: 
```
$("select[id*='CONTAIN-ID'] option:contains(MYVALUE)").attr('selected', 'selected')
```
but changing it using plain JS/Jquery doesn't update Orbeon's model, which is why I need a way to select an option using ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue

Comment: So there's no way to interact with ORBEON from jQuery? Ugh. So if the loop breaks at the option with the name, then `i` is the position, right? ORBEON doesn't let you set the selected by passing it `i`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, this is what I did:

```
myInitialValue = ORBEON.jQuery("select[id*='my-select-control'] option:contains(" + myInitialDisplayName + ")")[0].value; 

ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(ORBEON.jQuery(ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "my-select-control"]')[0]).find('.xforms-select1')[0], myInitialValue);
```